# Error loading assembly after renaming path

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a solution with severals projects i use for learning purpose. Recently i added a new class library project. I somehow accidently named it NinjaDomain,Classes instead of the intended NinjaDomain.Classes (dot instead of comma)

Before i realised it i had done som coding in this project and referenced it from other projects.

I renamed the folder manualy to NinjaDomain.Classes which was not a smart thing to do. So i have searched through every proj and the sln file and all the files that can be searchable through Visual Studios advanced find.

I have deleted and readded the references. Ive checked their properties and seen that they point to the correctly spelled path folder. 
I can build the project without errors at this point and i find no more misspellings but when i try to run the solutions MVC WebApi project i get this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'NinjaDomain\,Classes' or one of its dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'NinjaDomain\,Classes' or one of its dependencies. The given
>   assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131047)
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'NinjaDomain\,Classes' or one of its dependencies. The given assembly
>   name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)]
>   System.Reflection.AssemblyName.nInit(RuntimeAssembly& assembly,
>   Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean raiseResolveEvent) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.CreateAssemblyName(String
>   assemblyString, Boolean forIntrospection, RuntimeAssembly&
>   assemblyFromResolveEvent) +113
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr
>   pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +33
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +21    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString) +28
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'NinjaDomain\,Classes' or one of its dependencies. The given assembly
>   name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)]
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +726
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
>   +196    System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo
>   ai) +45
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection
>   compConfig) +172
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies()
>   +91    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String
>   preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +111
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +156
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +674
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly
>   'NinjaDomain\,Classes' or one of its dependencies. The given assembly
>   name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +772
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +95
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +195

Comment: Re-add the reference

Comment: Yep i have done this. Deleted and readded all references.

Comment: Try to search for *.csproj files manually (through windows explorer or FAR), open they in notepad, and search and replace `NinjaDomain,Classes` to `NinjaDomain.Classes` in them.
Can you find these string `NinjaDomain\,Classes` in *.csproj files?

Comment: ive looked throuhg them all. As well as the sln file.